# Redisson - RSortedSet

Tags: java, redisson

I need to preserve the ordering of elements added to a SET in Redis. In order to do that, I am using RSortedSet with a custom comparator.

The problem am facing here is, unlike RSetCache I am not able to expire the elements in this SET.

Is there a work-around to achieve this use case ?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, RSortedSet is implemented on top of a Redis LIST, not a SET. There is a RScoredSortedSet which is implemented on top of a Redis ZSET.

To achieve element expiry, as a work around, you can wrap it with another RExpirable object before adding into the RSortedSet. You just need to do some extra house keeping yourself: when you get an RExpirable object but it does not exist (`isExists` returns false), it means it is now expired. You can then delete it from the RSortedSet by yourself.